# Personalizing the d3 x axis labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm working on making a line graph, and after some googling I have come up with this:

```
function maxValue(input) {
          var current = 0;

          for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
              if (input[i] > current) {
                current = input[i];
              }
          }

          return current;
        }

        var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
        var w = 900 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
        var h = 600 - m[0] - m[2]; // height

        var data = [1, 6, 5, 12, 30, 45, 50, 48, 60, 69, 62, 80];

        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
                     "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                     "November", "December"];

        var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([1, 12]).range([0, w]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxValue(data)]).range([h, 0]);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d,i) { 
                return x(i + 1); 
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return y(d); 
            })

            var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
                  .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
                  .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
                .append("svg:g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true);
            graph.append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "x axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
                  .call(xAxis);


            var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(3).orient("left");
            graph.append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
                  .call(yAxisLeft);

            graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));

            graph.append("text")
              .attr("x", w/2)
              .attr("y", -20)
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .style("font-size", "18")
              .text("Total Hits in the Last Year");
```

As you can see, I made an array for the months of the year, and would like the x-axis to display months instead of a numeric value. But I can't tell where it says what to make the labels. Any know how to help? Thanks!

P.S. what does doing "svg:svg" do differently than just "svg?"

Edit:

```js
function maxValue(input) {
          var current = 0;
          
          for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
              if (input[i] > current) {
                current = input[i];
              }
          }
          
          return current;
        }
      
  var m = [80, 80, 80, 80]; // margins
  var w = 900 - m[1] - m[3]; // width
  var h = 600 - m[0] - m[2]; // height
      
  var data = [1, 6, 5, 12, 30, 45, 50, 48, 60, 69, 62, 80];

        var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
                     "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                     "November", "December"];
      
  var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([1, 12]).range([0, w]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxValue(data)]).range([h, 0]);

  var line = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d,i) { 
    return x(i + 1); 
   })
   .y(function(d) {
    return y(d); 
   })

   var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
         .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
         .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
       .append("svg:g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true);
   graph.append("svg:g")
         .attr("class", "x axis")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
         .call(xAxis);


   var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(3).orient("left");
   graph.append("svg:g")
         .attr("class", "y axis")
         .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
         .call(yAxisLeft);
   
     graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));
   
            graph.append("text")
              .attr("x", w/2)
              .attr("y", -20)
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .style("font-size", "18")
              .text("Total Hits in the Last Year");
```

```css
path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: none;
   }
   
   .axis {
     shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }

   .x.axis line {
     stroke: lightgrey;
   }

   .x.axis .minor {
     stroke-opacity: .5;
   }

   .x.axis path {
     display: none;
   }

   .y.axis line, .y.axis path {
     fill: none;
     stroke: #000;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Simple Line Graph</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="graph" class="aGraph" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0; float:left;"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please create working code snippet here?

Comment: @Dinesh There, I think I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the tickFormat function for the xAxis to fetch the month name from the array:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true).tickFormat(function(d) {
        return months[d-1]; 
    });
```